# Shuffling: Purpose and formal definition

Tags: side-channel-attack, permutation, pseudo-random-permutation

To my understanding, shuffling means simply to permute the elements in vector $\mathbf{v}$ pseudorandomly, using a PRP $\pi (\mathrm{seed},\mathbf{v})$. A secure PRP should yield a permutation indistinguishable from a random one.

However, I'd still have 2 questions on this subject:

1. Is there a more formal definition to shuffling?
2. What is the purpose of shuffling? Is it simply to misalign power traces for differential power analysis attacks?

Comment: What's the context? Shuffling is used in many context such a voting protocols, but als in oblivious data-structures.

Comment: I found it mentioned under the generic 'protecting encryption' label, so I suppose anything broad goes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In side channel, shuffling makes correlation attacks harder. For example, if you shuffle the 16 AES S-Boxes in the first round each execution, and you target say first S-Box' output in the attack, at any single point in the trace you will see information related directly to that output only on 1/16th of all traces, and in the other 15/16th traces there will be something else, which qualifies as "noise" for the attack.

Note that this countermeasure is rather weak and is mostly considered complimentary to more sound *masking countermeasure*. Indeed, after taking 16 times more traces (maybe a bit more), the correlation would become noticeable again. While this adds up to the practical attack complexity, it is impossible to achieve exponential complexity increase, as masking allows.

Comment: Thanks! I know this is out of the scope of the original question, but could you detail a bit about how masking (simple, higher-order) works and how it can be used together with shuffling? You also mentioned masking trumps shuffling in terms of security. Why is that?

Comment: Are there any paper for the claims?

Comment: @kelalaka CHES 2009 paper by Rivain et al. may be a good start https://ia.cr/2009/420